# While loop and curl, junk in submission url

Tags: php, curl, while-loop

I need to submit a bunch of data from a CSV to a url via a post string, to accomplish this I'm doing the following:

```
<?php

$CSVleadfile = "leads.csv";

//lead file information lookup

$f = fopen($CSVleadfile, "r");

//begin while loop

while($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
        $contactId = $row[1];
        $createDate = $row[2];
        $callerAni = $row[3];
        $tfn = $row[4];
        $firstname = $row[5];
        $lastname = $row[6];
        $address1 = $row[7];
        $address2 = $row[8];
        $city = $row[9];
        $state = $row[10];
        $zip = $row[11];
        $homephone = $row[12];
        $email = $row[13];      

// load data for posting array

$post_data = array(
"Prs_First" => "$firstname",
"Prs_Middle" => "",
"Prs_Last" => "$lastname",
"Prs_Email" => "$email",
"Prs_Phone1" => "$homephone",
"Prs_Phone2" => "$callerAni",
"Prs_Address1" => "$address1",
"Prs_Address2" => "$address2",
"Prs_City" => "$city",
"Prs_State" => "$state",
"Prs_Zip" => "$zip",
"InitialContactDate" => "$createDate",
);

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)

unset($post_items);

foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the string to be posted using implode()

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection

$curl_connection = curl_init('https://www.whatever.com');

//echo to make sure string is formed correctly 

echo "Submitting: <br />";
echo "$post_string";
echo "<br />";


//set options

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform the request

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

$result = simplexml_load_string($result);
$result = json_encode($result);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo "<br />";
if (isset($result)){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "$result";
print_r($result[0]);
echo "$result[0]";
echo "</pre>";
} else {
echo "it's still broken.";
$result = "Still TFB";
}
echo "<br />";

unset($curl_connection);
unset($result);
unset($post_string);

}

//end while loop

fclose($f);

?>
```

Now, the problem I'm having is two fold: first I never see any results ever from that echo at the end, regardless if I try to echo $result or print_r. The second problem is that this takes FOREVER. We're talking like 30 second a submission.... which makes me wonder if it's timing out for some reason? I've never used curl inside a while loop like this before, so I'm not sure if there is some sort of additional cleanup I need to do... or some way to echo back more information for troubleshooting from curl. I'm starting to feel like I'm at my wits end... Halp!

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I've tossed the curl function outside the loop as suggested:

```
<?php

$CSVleadfile = "testing.csv";

//lead file information lookup

$f = fopen($CSVleadfile, "r");

while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
$contactId = $row[1];
$createDate = $row[2];
$callerAni = $row[3];
$tfn = $row[4];
$firstname = $row[5];
$lastname = $row[6];
$address1 = $row[7];
$address2 = $row[8];
$city = $row[9];
$state = $row[10];
$zip = $row[11];
$homephone = $row[12];
$email = $row[13];

// load data for posting array
$post_data = array(
    "that" => "$junk",
);

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode('&', $post_items);


//perform the request
executeCurl();

}

//outside loop curl function

function executeCurl() {

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =      curl_init('https://www.whatever.com');

//set options

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);


$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

$result = simplexml_load_string($result);

echo "<br />";
if (isset($result)) {
    var_dump($result);
    die;
} else {
    echo "it's still broken.";
    $result = "Still TFB";
}
echo "<br />";

file_put_contents("./Results.txt", $results, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

fclose($f);
?>
```

I've stripped the json weirdness out of there... honestly cant remember why I tossed that in there, pretty sure it might have been formatting but either way the result that I'm expecting is something like:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.whatever.com">11940576</string>
```

and that's what I'd like to record back to that text file :D No changes in behavior though :( my var_dump results in bool(false)

Comment: For one, it's better to reuse the connection if you can, i.e. move the `curl_init()` outside of the loop. Also, what's up with the `simplexml_load_string() -> json_encode() -> json_decode()` code? What are you expecting to receive?

Comment: #1, I would use file_get_contents() instead of fopen/fclose/etc. That should help reduce some complexity here.

#2, What do you expect to get as a response from the cURL POST?

#3, Try `var_dump($result); die;` to see exactly what's being spit out of the cURL request.

Comment: @c.hill `file_get_contents()` won't work well with `fgetcsv()` though; perhaps you could use `str_getcsv()` but that wouldn't be memory efficient.

Comment: @Jack I've tried moving it outside the loop (and updated above) but I'm still having the same issue with it... I suspect that something is either being overwritten per loop, or that my curl is malformed somehow... but other then that I'm totally in the dark

Comment: You have moved the code into a function declaration that's outside of the loop, but you're still calling it at every iteration step. You should put the `curl_init()` outside of the loop and pass that to your function instead; also, put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script.

Comment: Turns out it was a firewall issue ;_; Thanks so much for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: Why do you convert your post data array into a string? Curl happily accepts an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, and using an array there wil additionally set the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data.

Issue 2: curl will accept multiple options at once with `curl_setopt_array()`.